# Is Walgreens legally liable for lost film?

Tags: united-states, liability, washington

If I gave a roll of film to Walgreens to develop and they lost it, what are my chances of winning if I sue them for the time spent to take the photos in addition to the film?

Comment: This sounds like a request for legal advice, to me.

Comment: Read your contract with Walgreens, it's on the envelope you put the film in and the receipt you got.

Comment: @nick012000 What makes it sound like a request for legal advice? It sounds much more like a hypothetical to me.

Comment: What century did you lose it in?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question; suppose it happens tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what are my chances of winning if I sue them for the time spent to
> take the photos in addition to the film?

Virtually nil. Typically, there would be a contractual limitation of liability to getting the money you paid to have them developed back and perhaps the cost  of the film.

This limitation of liability would typically be upheld in court unless the reason the film was lost was due to an intentional or reckless act of the film developer, or perhaps "gross negligence" or "willful and wanton" conduct.

Comment: Thanks! This does make me wonder whether the limitation of liability extends to all services involving operating on people's possessions, so perhaps I'll ask a new question.

Comment: @merlin2011 The limitation of liability is contractual, not as a matter of law. In some fields it is common, in others it is not.

Comment: Don't most service providers try to disclaim as much as possible in their contracts? But a court may find that there's a minimum standard of care or duty that they can't disclaim away.

Comment: @Barmar I've stated the main limitation in the answer.